# How to replace raphaeljs boxes with draggable html div's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, raphael

I am creating UML Class diagram using Raphaeljs , I have created somehow using boxes but that looks awful. I want to add draggable div's instead of draggable boxes. That should be in the same way the boxes are i.e. connection line moves with the movement of box.
How can I replace these boxes with draggable div's?

**Any other ways to do thing like this will also be appreciated**

This is my first or second question here. So, forgive me if the question is ambiguous please have a look on the fiddle to understand what I am actually asking 
 
This is how I did it with boxes

```
var boxes = [
  {x:200,y:100,text:'User  \n--------------------------------\n Login ()\n 
  Signup () \n ViewProduct ()  '}, 
  {x:400,y:400,text:'Product  \n--------------------------------\n 
  AddProduct ()\n DeleteProduct () \n UpdateProduct ()  '},
  {x:1000,y:430,text:'Cart  \n--------------------------------\n AddtoCart 
  ()\n DeleteFromCart () \n ResetCart () '}
   ];


 var connections = [
 {from:boxes[0], to:boxes[1]},  {from:boxes[1], to:boxes[2]} ];
```

Here's the Fiddle [UML Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bw0eq56m/)

Comment: The "---------" is to give it a look like UML , because it is not allowing me to write html in boxes :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you want them to *look* like Dialog boxes or do you want to actually make jQuery Objects that are `.dialog()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found infobox, and looked at what they did: https://github.com/kreynolds/RaphaelJS-Infobox/blob/master/raphaeljs-infobox.js

It sort of works, and I was hoping Raphael would help something with a `<foreignobject>` element within the SVG, but it does not look like they include that. I've never used it before. So I may look into it further or see if I can inject it into the `paper` another way so that you get:

```
<svg width="500" height="300" style="border:1px red solid">
  <foreignobject class="node" x="46" y="22" width="100" height="100">
    <div style="border:1px green solid">I'm a div inside a SVG.</div>                
  </foreignobject>
</svg>
```

What I have gotten to so far is this:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pq7p05nc/1/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  // Model
  var boxes = [{
    x: 109,
    y: 120,
    text: 'User  \n--------------------------------\n Login ()\n Signup () \n ViewProduct ()  '
  }, {
    x: 180,
    y: 270,
    text: 'Product  \n--------------------------------\n AddProduct ()\n DeleteProduct () \n UpdateProduct ()  '
  }, {
    x: 370,
    y: 230,
    text: 'Cart  \n--------------------------------\n AddtoCart ()\n DeleteFromCart () \n ResetCart () '
  }];

  var connections = [{
    from: boxes[0],
    to: boxes[1]
  }, {
    from: boxes[1],
    to: boxes[2]
  }];

  // Render
  var paper = new Raphael($('#paper')[0], 700, 500);
  var w = 100;
  var h = 100;

  function redraw() {

    connections.forEach(function(connection) {
      if (typeof connection.view != 'undefined') {
        connection.view.remove();
      }
      connection.view = paper.path(
        'M' + connection.from.x + ',' + connection.from.y + ' ' +
        'L' + connection.to.x + ',' + connection.to.y
      );
      connection.view.toBack();
    });

    var i = 0;
    boxes.forEach(function(box) {
      if (typeof box.view == 'undefined') {
        box.view = {
          rect: paper.rect(-h / 2, -h / 2, w, h),
          text: paper.text(0, 0, box.text)
        };
        box.view.c_id = box.view.rect.node.parentNode.parentNode.id ? box.view.rect.node.parentNode.parentNode.id : box.view.rect.node.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
        box.view.div_c = $("#" + box.view.c_id);
        box.view.div = $("<div>", {
            id: "ui-box-" + i++,
            class: "dialog-box",
            title: box.text.slice(0, box.text.indexOf("\n"))
          })
          .html(box.text.slice(box.text.indexOf("\n", 12)))
          .appendTo(box.view.div_c)
          .dialog({
            position: {
              my: "left top",
              at: "left+" + box.x + " top+" + box.y,
              of: "#" + box.view.c_id
            },
            width: w,
            height: h + 20
          });
        console.log(box, box.view.div.position());
        box.view.rect.attr({
          //fill: 'lightyellow'
        });
        box.view.rect.drag(function(dx, dy, x, y) {
          box.x = x;
          box.y = y;
        });
      }
      var tbox = 't' + box.x + ',' + box.y;
      box.view.rect.transform(tbox);
      box.view.text.transform(tbox);
    });
  }

  // Controller
  var a = 0;

  function slide() {
    a += 0;
    redraw();
    setTimeout(slide, 10);
  }
  slide();
});
```

This does append the `<div>` and make it dialog, yet it's not within the `<svg>`. I suspect this will not cause much issue for your `drag` events, but they should be moved into the dialogs `drag` callback to retain the "connections".

This achieves what you originally asked about, yet I suspect you have more rabbit holes to dig in now.

**Update 1**

Fixed position, hide close button, and updated drag: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pq7p05nc/3/

**CSS**

```
.dialog-box .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
  display: none;
}

.dialog-box .ui-dialog-titlebar {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.125em;
}

.dialog-box .ui-dialog-content {
  padding: 0.2em;
}
```

**JS**

```
box.view.div = $("<div>", {
  id: "ui-box-" + i++,
  title: box.text.slice(0, box.text.indexOf("\n"))
})
.html(box.text.slice(box.text.indexOf("\n", 12)).replace("/\n/g", "<br />"))
.appendTo(box.view.div_c)
.dialog({
  classes: {
    "ui-dialog": "dialog-box ui-corner-all"
  },
  position: {
    my: "left top",
    at: "left+" + (box.x - (w / 2) - 2) + " top+" + (box.y - (h / 2) - 2),
    of: "#" + box.view.c_id
  },
  width: w,
  height: h,
  drag: function(e, ui) {
    box.x = ui.position.left + (w / 2);
    box.y = ui.position.top + (h / 2);
  }
});
```

You could suppress creating the rect & text at this point of hide them.

**Update 2**

Added containment and hide the SCG rect and text.

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pq7p05nc/5/

```
drag: function(e, ui) {
  if (ui.position.left >= $("#paper svg").width() - (w / 2)) {
    ui.position.left = $("#paper svg").width() - (w / 2);
  }
  if (ui.position.top >= $("#paper svg").height() - (h / 2)) {
    ui.position.top = $("#paper svg").height() - (h / 2);
  }
  box.x = ui.position.left + (w / 2);
  box.y = ui.position.top + (h / 2);
}
```

Comment: This is not working on my pc:/ I added the jquery cdn it shows rough lines :/ any idea why ?

Comment: Any alerts info your console? Hard to tell why.

Comment: This is what I am getting, it works fine on fiddle but the problem arrives while running on pc as .html file.
Link is :
https://ibb.co/iZuNa5

Comment: The jQuery library is not loading. What's in your `<head>`?

Comment: <head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">  </script>
<script src="js/raphael.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js">  </script>
</head>

Comment: Need to add http or https. Https:// code.jquery.com.... know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

The code works great , thanks man. @twisty.

I was doing a little thing wrong.

```
 var boxes = [{
x: 109,
y: 120,
text: 'User \n--------------------------------\n <a href="asdsad.html" 
style="text-decoration:none">USERID \n<br> Name\n<br> Address\n <hr> Login 
()
<br>Signup ()<br> </a>'
 }, {
x: 180,
y: 270,
 text: 'Product  \n--------------------------------\n ProdID \n<br> 
 Name\n<br> 
  Storeid\n <hr>GetPRoduct()<br>DeleteProduct()<br> ViewProduct ()'
 }, {
  x: 370,
 y: 230,
 text: 'Cart  \n--------------------------------\n Cartid \n<br> Items\n<br> 
 Type\n<br>  <hr> AddProduct()<br>RemoveProduct ()<br> ViewCart ()'  
 }];

 var connections = [{
from: boxes[0],
to: boxes[1]
  }, {
from: boxes[1],
to: boxes[2]
   }];
```

JS FIDDLE [UML Class Diagram](https://jsfiddle.net/nhzaag3m/)
This link is for those who want to generate uml class diagram using JS.